# apt wants to autoremove automatically installed recommended packages despite settings in apt.conf.d

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

When I'm running `apt upgrade`, it suggests me to auto-remove several dozens of essential packages using `apt autoremove`.

They include `busybox`, `bluetooth` and `alsa-utils` among other important packages which were all marked as automatically installed & recommended packages in the aptitude interface.

aptitude, however, does not want these packages to be auto-removed when pressing <kbd>g</kbd> for preview. This inconsistency really puzzles me. aptitude's configuration to install recommended packages is set to default, which is `true`, therefore it works as expected.

This strange auto-remove inconsistency with apt started when I created a new file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` prefixed with `99` to auto-remove all recommended packages using the following instructions:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant "false";
APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";
```

And then I changed my mind, and decided to keep the recommended packages but not the suggested packages as a compromise.

```
APT::Install-Recommends "true";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant "false";
APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";
```

It clearly instructs apt to install & keep recommended packages, but not the suggested packages.

Why does apt want these packages to be auto-removed if they're recommended when `APT::Install-Recommends` is set to `true`?

I'm using the testing version of Debian Buster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It clearly instructs apt to install & keep recommended packages, but not the suggested packages.

No, it instructs `apt` to install recommended packages, but not to keep them. You need to specify

```
APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant "true";
```

if you want `apt` to keep recommended packages.

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works! I thought it does exactly the opposite and keeps the important recommended packages from being auto-removed. Thank you again!